# JQuery textfield only accepts numbers as input, this works well but when I use my numpad it does not work

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want my JQuery code to only accept numbers as input in the textfield, this code is working well for me but soon discovered that if I used the numbers in my numpad it does not work. Any suggestions for this problem guys?

Here is my code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(".txtboxToFilterNum").keydown(function(event) {

        if (event.keyCode == 46 || event.keyCode == 8 || event.keyCode == 9 || event.keyCode == 0 || event.keyCode == 13 || event.keyCode == 27) {
            // let it happen, don't do anything
        }
        else {
            // Ensure that it is a NUMBER and stop the keypress
            if (event.keyCode < 48 || event.keyCode > 57 ) {
                event.preventDefault(); 
            }   
        }
});
</script>
```

Comment: Your keypad is returning different keycodes. Instead, check the textbox value on key up or onChange, and remove the last character if it's not a number

Comment: Numpad keycodes are different. See for example this page for the codes: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/AS2LCR/Flash_10.0/help.html?content=00000520.html

Comment: possible duplicate of [Allow only Numbers in text box using jquery with out extra plugins](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8635381/allow-only-numbers-in-text-box-using-jquery-with-out-extra-plugins)

Comment: It would be easier to use [`oninput`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Reference/Events/input) instead of bunch of events.

Comment: Noted, thank you very much for the reply. Will try my best to figure this out.

Answer (score 0):

Do not check which key is pressed, but which content is given, it will be easier to check if the content are numbers only, and it will prevent many other things such as using copy and paste with letters (I guess this is not handled in your given code too)

Comment: I do have a script that disables the copy paste function and it also working well.

Comment: Alright, still a bit sad to disable the whole copy/paste function instead of checking the content, maybe your user would paste numbers, but I guess it depends what you're doing with your textfield

Answer (score 0):

[working sample](http://jsfiddle.net/Lm2hS/)

**HTML**

```
<input type="text" class="textfield" value="" id="extra7" name="extra7" onkeypress="return isNumber(event)" />
```

**Javascript**

```
function isNumber(evt) {
    evt = (evt) ? evt : window.event;
    var charCode = (evt.which) ? evt.which : evt.keyCode;
    if (charCode > 31 && (charCode < 48 || charCode > 57)) {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: This works well, but with my current design I may have to change everything all over again with this code but thanks though.

Comment: No need to change a lot.Just add this piece of code "onkeypress="return isNumber(event)"" in your html textbox and place javascript..thats it..

Comment: that's exactly the problem, i have many textboxes that is using my current function. About 50-70 textboxes. Already found a solution though. Thanks for the help!